# Cannot export vCard on iCloud

Tags: icloud

I need to export my contacts to my Google account but whenever I select all of my contacts and click export vCard, the website does not do anything.

Comment: I tried Safari, Chrome, IE, and Edge and they all either no response when I select export to .vcf or just exported the first one only. Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

It can work using Google Chrome and Microsoft Internet Explorer :

With Chrome: do a **right** click on the menu option 'export vcard'

With I.E.: do a **SHIFT-Click** on the menu option 'export vcard'

Answer (score 1):

I just found out myself, that it won't work if you use Chrome or Internet Explorer, but it works when you use Safari to extract your contacts.

Comment: This is completely true! I am using a mac and this was the only reason why i could import the vcard. How can one secure the fate of a Windows user with such faulty software?!

Comment: You could try the old Safari for Windows. Apple don't have it anymore, but [Techspot](http://www.techspot.com/downloads/4184-safari-for-windows.html) have the file

Answer (score 0):

It should export as a single item to your defined Downloads folder, titled
`FirstName InTheList and 27 others.vcf`

Comment: sometimes exporting the vcard does not lead to a download

Answer (score 0):

Works well with Firefox. I could export contacts successfully using Firefox.

Answer (score -2):

Just Install latest Safari Browser, wow it will work with perfect.

sam